# Eigen losing negative sign in matrix addition

Tags: c++, matlab, eigen

I am trying to add a matrix using Eigen library and my result is numerically ok but it is missing the negative sign. The result after the addition in correct it is the final addition that lose the negative sign. All matrices are declare as double.

I have this code in both cases:

```
for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
 mata<<MatrixXd::Zero(4,4);
  for(int j=0;i<4;j++){
   mata += matb.transpose()*(matc*matb)*scalar;
  }
 cout<<mata<<endl;
}
```

I have also try:

```
for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
 mata<<MatrixXd::Zero(4,4);
  for(int j=0;i<4;j++){
   MatrixXd aux=matb.transpose();
   MatrixXd aux2=(matc*matb)*scalar
   mata += aux*aux2;
  }
 cout<<mata<<endl;
}
```

Matlab result:

```
    1.92186   -0.960928   -0.960928 -5.55112e-17
  -0.960928     1.92186 -5.55112e-17   -0.960928
  -0.960928 -5.55112e-17     1.92186   -0.960928
-5.55112e-17   -0.960928   -0.960928     1.92186
```

Eigen result:

```
    1.92186   -0.960928   -0.960928 5.55112e-17
  -0.960928     1.92186 5.55112e-17   -0.960928
  -0.960928 5.55112e-17     1.92186   -0.960928
5.55112e-17   -0.960928   -0.960928     1.92186
```

Answer (score 7):

This is a result of the precision in the floating point calculations.  The slightly different order between the two (the first does all the matrix multiplications first, then scales by `scale`, while the second scales before the last matrix multiply) result in the least significant bit or two of the floating point result being different during the various additions and subtractions of the last matrix multiply.

The number you're seeing (5.55112e-17) is, for all practical purposes here, effectively 0 and the results are identical.